# Postgres memory usage grows over time, resets when clients restarted

Tags: postgresql, memory, connections

I have a Postgres DB running on the same small server as some applications that use it. Immediately after restarting the applications, Postgres uses <100 MB memory. After a few days without restarting, this climbs to >1GB. The memory usage of the clients doesn't increase correspondingly, and the total number of connections stays roughly constant. What could be the reason for this growth? [This](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/52AEFDA7.4010900%40gmail.com) says "Every additional table touched will pull in some more metadata, so over the course of a long lived connection in the pool, it could grow a lot if you have a lot of tables."

postgresql.conf details:

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 512MB
work_mem = 4MB
```

(but usually there are only around 20 connections)

I'm running Postgres and the applications Docker containers. The server has 4GB RAM.

Comment: Unlikely, unless you keep transactions open. How do you measure this?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe What do you mean? I have long-living connections but not long-running queries. I'm measuring memory consumption with `docker stats` (the consumption displayed by the message when I ssh in agrees).

Comment: That's what I meant. I don't know what `docker stats` measures. The next step would be to figure out which process uses all that memory, and what part of it is shared memory.

Comment: Over time, almost all of the PostgreSQL processes will eventually touch all of the shared_buffers.  Then each one can get individually credited with "using" that memory, even though it is the same memory.  Is there an actual problem, like high swap/paging or out of memory errors?

Comment: @jjanes I had problems with the whole system running out of memory in the past but I don't know if they were due to Postgres. I'll let it ramp up and see if it starts swapping.

Comment: @rlms did you come to any conclusions?